# How to scale all columns except certain ones in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

With the following example code all columns are scaled with MinMaxScaler.
How to change in order to only scale column A and column C? Ideally I want to do it by excluding column B by name.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
                           'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68],
                           'C':[3,5,4,2,3]})

df[df.columns] = scaler.fit_transform(df[df.columns])
```

Comment: `df[["A","C"]] = scaler.fit_transform(df[["A","C"]])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`pandas.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html?highlight=difference#pandas.Index.difference):

```py
scaler.fit_transform(df[df.columns.difference(['B'])])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'B']
df[cols] = scaler.fit_transform(df[cols])
```